# Laravel with nginx server and AWS RDS got "too many connections" error

Tags: mysql, laravel, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I'm facing a problem with my Laravel app running under nginx web server (an **EC2** instance) and a remote DB connection to my **AWS RDS** (MySQL).

I've already scaled it up from **t2.micro** to **t2.large** for both of my EC2 and RDS, but MySQL still produced

> too many connections

and

> cannot allocate memory

error in my nginx log.

My RDS has max. **312** MySQL connections and I've used **PDO persistent** on my Laravel database config but it still doesn't solve the issue.

Do I have to scale it up to the higher instance level or is there anything wrong with my architecture?

Any answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We went through a problem similar to this for a short time, we will solve the following problem:

1 - We use Aurora replicas. You can use replicas using the resource or the cluster

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVcmh.png

2 - We modify the parameters of the institution. max_execution_time by default or unlimited RDS mounts. We place or limit as 10000.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7Ccb.png

3 - Assets for slow query (slow_query_log) of the cluster. Displays all queries that exceed 10 seconds of execution. Command, browsing optimizing queries.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7HX4.png

We have no more problems than we do. I hope I have helped.